# Create a Task that groups several I/O Tasks

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, sqlcommand

First of all, I am not sure if I am asking something stupid, so apologies before start.

I have a method that saves a collection of entities in the DB using a SqlCommand asynchronously, and it returns a Task that represents the async operation, and so far it works good. Basically it generates a SQL command and a bunch of parameters per entity, and add all of them to a SqlCommand instance (parameters are numbered)

But, if I try to insert a lot of entities, when the parameter count reaches 2100, the SQL  operation fails, because that is the limit. Then I would like to split the entity collection in batches, and execute them sequentially, and then return a Task that won't be done till all the child Tasks are done. (probably the last one)

Each child task, will get a Int32 saying how many rows have changed, and the final Task has to return the sum of all of them. So all the task are Task. If one fails, all of them must be "rollbacked", so they must share connection and transaction objects.

Also, I would like to ensure that I am using correctly the I/O completion ports with the Task and SqlCommand, and that there are no threads waiting/spining while the operations on SQL Server are being done, since this "Save" operation is invoked from an asynchronous controller in ASP.NET MVC.

What would be the correct approach here?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C# 5 (and assuming Task-based asynchrony), this would be quite simple:

```
async Task<IReadOnlyList<SomeType>> PerformUpdatesAsync(
    IEnumerable<AnotherType> data)
{
    var result = new List<SomeType>();

    foreach (var batch in data.SplitIntoBatches(BatchSize))
        result.Add(await PerformUpdateAsync(batch));

    return result;
}
```

Simulating asynchronous `foreach` in pre-C# 5 is harder, but you can do it for example using a queue of batches to process and a “recursive” lambda:

```
Task<SomeType[]> PerformUpdatesAsync(IEnumerable<AnotherType> data)
{
    var batches = new Queue<IEnumerable<AnotherType>>(
        data.SplitIntoBatches(BatchSize));

    var result = new List<SomeType>();

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SomeType[]>();

    AsyncCallback onEndUpdate = null;
    onEndUpdate =
        ar =>
        {
            result.Add(EndUpdate(ar));

            if (batches.Count == 0)
                tcs.SetResult(result.ToArray());
            else
                BeginUpdate(batches.Dequeue(), onEndUpdate, null);
        };

    BeginUpdate(batches.Dequeue(), onEndUpdate, null);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

If you don't like using closures this way, you could do the same thing by creating a separate class that will hold all the local variables in its fields.

There is no `SplitIntoBatches()` in the framework, and so you will have to write it yourself (unless you already did).

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to split the inserts up, but run them sequentially, you don't need to use Tasks for each call. You just need normal sequential code.

Create a method that starts a Task and returns it. In the task body, just execute whatever normal sequential code you want. When you have finished, exit the task body and the single Task will complete.

Comment: Well, almost. This way, the background thread that executes the SQL operations will block. To avoid that, you can write the code asynchronously and use `TaskCompletionSource` to create and set the result of the `Task`.

Comment: @svick that is what I do not know how to do it. Run several asynchronous operations sequentially with accumulative results...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. Here is some code:

```
Task<int>[] batchTasks = ...;//start the batches here. each task should return the count of changed rows
Task<int> sumTask = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(batchTasks, _ => {
 return batchTasks.Sum(x => x.Result);
});
```

This will give you a blocking-free total sum of the individual batches.

When you start a batch be sure to use the async SQL APIs like BeginExecuteReader. Then, you will be completely blocking-free.

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake, I want to run the child tasks sequentially, not in parallel, since I cannot use the same connection for concurrent calls. I have edited the post. Basically, I want to return a task that would be the last in the chain and contains the total result. Sorry about that.